# Zend framework uploading file and setting destination problems

Tags: file, zend-framework, upload, path

I've got a problem with uploading a file with ZF.
This is my application structure:

```
//application
//images
index.php
//library
//styles
//public
  //img
```

The application path in index.php seems to be ok:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')  
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));
```

When i try to upload a file i get a message (such a dir does not exist).

This is my controllers code snippet:

```
$upload->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '../public/img/');
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your APPLICATION_PATH is not followed by a slash. Invoke setDestination() like this:

```
$upload->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/img/');
```

Comment: That's true. Now everything's ok. Thanks a lot for help.